# How do I make an alias for a Unix command that includes both single and double quotes?

Tags: shell, alias

I defined the following command:

```
top -b n 2 -d 0.01 | grep 'Cpu' | tail -n 1 | awk '{print "cpu=" 100.0-$8 "%"}'
```

which returns me the CPU usage in the form

```
cpu=nn%
```

I now want to define the alias 'cpu' for the above command, but I have quotes and double quotes in it.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pick one, and either remove the need for, or escape the other.** For example, using `""` to indicate the string boundaries (which seems easier in this particular case), we first place quotation marks around the string:

```
alias cpu="top -b n 2 -d 0.01 | grep 'Cpu' | tail -n 1 | awk '{print "cpu=" 100.0-$8 "%"}'"
```

Then, we need to escape the inner quotation marks so they do not terminate the string as seen by the shell:

```
alias cpu="top -b n 2 -d 0.01 | grep 'Cpu' | tail -n 1 | awk '{print \"cpu=\" 100.0-$8 \"%\"}'"
```

Then, `$8` becomes a shell variable expansion (rather than an awk variable expression) in this context, so we need to escape that as well. This would not have been needed if we had been able to use `''` (straight apostrophes) to indicate the string boundaries to the shell.

```
alias cpu="top -b n 2 -d 0.01 | grep 'Cpu' | tail -n 1 | awk '{print \"cpu=\" 100.0-\$8 \"%\"}'"
```

After running **the final version above,** it works:

```
$ alias cpu="top -b n 2 -d 0.01 | grep 'Cpu' | tail -n 1 | awk '{print \"cpu=\" 100.0-\$8 \"%\"}'"
$ alias | grep '^alias cpu='
alias cpu='...'
$ cpu
cpu=nn%
$
```